# Quartz scheduler interrupting job?

Tags: java, spring, scheduling, quartz-scheduler

I have a quartz job. i need to stop its processing through UI. we provide a button where in user can click `STOP` button then current running process should be stopped. but further scheduling should resume. i googled and found `InterruptableJob` of quartz.

My question is, consider the job has triggered a stored procedure execution and stored procedure might take long time to complete its execution. i believe `InterruptableJob` cannot kill the stored procedure execution using interrupt method of InterruptableJob.
Please can someone explain in which scenario `interrupt() of InterruptableJob` is useful?

i went through  http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/InterruptableJob.html but dont know in which case i need to use this.

Thanks!